# How to implement access control for individual object in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket which is by default private.
Now I want to implement access control on the objects of this bucket.

For example, if bucket has three objects A, B, C then object A, B could be public and object C could be private.

It should be possible to make the public object private and vice-versa from the application. The private objects will be accessible by selected **application users** only and public objects will be accessible by everyone.
Is there any way to implement it?

So far I have looked into [object tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html). But I am not entirely sure if it applies in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that objects in Amazon S3 are private by default.

You can then grant access via several methods:

- Set the **Access Control List (ACL)** on an individual object to make it Public (or set it back to being Private)
- Create a **Bucket Policy** to grant access to a whole bucket, or a path within a bucket
- Add a policy to an **IAM User** to allow that user access to all/part of an Amazon S3 bucket
- Create **Pre-signed URLs** to grant time-limited access to a private object

So, you can certainly make specific objects Public and then change them to Private by using ACLs.

To make particular objects accessible to particular users, you should use **Pre-Signed URLs**. They work as follows:

- Users **authenticate** to your application
- When a user wishes to access a private object, the application is responsible for determining whether they are permitted to access it
- If so, then the application generates a **pre-signed URL**. It only takes a few lines of code and does not require an API call to S3.
- The application then provides the pre-signed URL just like any other link, such as putting it in an `<a>` tag, or in an `<img>` tag. The object will be accessible for a limited time duration just like any other resource on the Internet.
- Once the duration has expired, the URL will no longer work (Access Denied)

This way, your application is totally in control of who can access which objects and authorized users can access the objects directly from Amazon S3. Also, the application users do not require AWS-specific logins; they would authenticate to your application.

See: [Share an Object with Others - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)